# Error when retrieving data from fireStore using collectionData

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this firestore db that stores some data, but I have a problem when I try to fetch records from it.

My code is supposed to give a record of users, but gives the error:

> ERROR FirebaseError: Expected type 'Query', but it was: a custom wh object.

here is my code

```js
import { Firestore, addDoc, collection, collectionData } from '@angular/fire/firestore'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private fs: Firestore) { }

  addToFireStore(data: any) {
    const collectionInstance = collection(this.fs, 'users')
    addDoc(collectionInstance, data).then(() => {
      console.log('saved successfully')
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
  }

  getDataFromFireStore() {
    const collectionInstance = collection(this.fs, 'users')
    collectionData(collectionInstance).subscribe(val => console.log(val))
  }
}
```

here is the package.json

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
     ...
    "@angular/fire": "7.6.1",
    "firebase": "^10.4.0",
    "rxfire": "6.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working using `getDoc()`, and `getDocs()` instead of using `collectionData()` & `docData()`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { Firestore, addDoc, collection, doc, getDoc, getDocs } from '@angular/fire/firestore'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private fs: Firestore) { }

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log(this.userForm.value)
    this.addToFireStore(this.userForm.value)
  }

  addToFireStore(data: any) {
    const collectionInstance = collection(this.fs, 'users')
    addDoc(collectionInstance, data)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('saved successfully')
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  }


  async getDataFromFirestore() {
    const collectionRef = collection(this.fs, 'users')
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef)
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log('Document ID: ', doc.id)
        console.log('Data: ', doc.data(), doc)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data: ', error)
    }
  }


  async getNoteById(id = 'id') {

    const docRef = doc(this.fs, `users/${id}`)
    const querySnapshot = await getDoc(docRef)
    console.log(querySnapshot.data())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using the Firestore methods in combination with Angular Fire.

Angular Firestore

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  addToFireStore(data: any) {
    this.firestore.collection('users').add(data)
      .then(() => console.log('saved successfully'))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  getDataFromFireStore() {
    this.firestore.collection('users').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }
}
```

ngModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const firebaseConfig = {
  // your firebase config here
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: gives this error
Module '"@angular/fire/firestore"' has no exported member 'AngularFireStore'.ts(2305)
and 
```AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)```

isn't this the old way of initializing Firebase.